What is the comapctness argument mentioned here?
Following is the proof of Darboux's Theorem in John M Lee's Book. Can someone explain the compactness argument mentioned in the proof? I have highlighted the part using the compactness argument in the screenshot.
This screenshot is from page 573, proof of Theorem 22.13 in this pdf https://julianchaidez.net/materials/reu/lee_smooth_manifolds.pdf


This is commonly called the Tube Lemma.
